# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el nombre del usuario que esta logueado, en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente problema, en mi aplicación voy a registrar muchos usuarios, y cuando ellos guarden información en una tabla, quiero que el nombre del usuario quede guardado o el ID de ese usuario guardado en esa misma tabla, para saber qué usuario almacenó esa información.

---

hasta el momento llevo esto, pero no guarda:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Permite almacenar un nuevo deposito 
    $this->validate($request,[
        'noboleta'=>'required',
        'monto'=>'required|numeric|min:1,max:14',
        'id_banco'=>'required',
        'id_tipo'=>'required',
        'id_estado'=>'required',
        'fechaboleta'=>'required',
        'detalles'=>'required|alpha',
        ]);
        $deposito['id_usuario'] = \Auth::user()->id;
        $deposito->save(); 
    Deposito::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('depositos.index')
        ->with('success','Deposito Guardado');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuperas el id del usuario:

```
$idUser=\Auth::user()->id;
```

Y lo guardas en el campo que corresponda del Modelo

```
$modelo= new Modelo();
$modelo->idUser=$idUser;
$modelo->save();
```

Comment: me genera un error, dice que la class App\Auth no existe.